# How to find which link is active link in top menu in mvc view

Tags: jquery, css

I have a top  menu in `mvc view`. I need to make the menu item change its color when the user is in that page. How I can find which link is the active link so that I can change the color?

**This is the menu code:**

```
<div class="secondary-nav">
@Html.ActionLink("DashBoard", "Dashboard", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand-active" })

@if (visible)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Loan Driver", "Search", "LoanDriver", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
}
@if (manageUser)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Manage Users", "UserManagement", "User", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
}
@Html.ActionLink("Contract Repository", "ContractRepositorySearch", "ContractRepository", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

Comment: give same class to each link, then check that is these class has any navbar-brand-active link, if you find any then it is active...

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("DashBoard", "DashBoard", "Home", null, new { @class = "my-class" })
```

**css**

```
a.my-class { color: #333333 }
a.my-class:active { color: #666666 }
a.my-class:link { color: #999999 }
a.my-class:visited { color: #CCCCCC }
```

Comment: the problem is how I can find which one is active/ current page link?